# Redirecting to PhaseListener from doPost method of Servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, httpresponse

I want to call `PhaseListener` from doPost method of a `Servlet`. How can I do that?

I dont want to do like this

`RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/html/index.jsf");`
`dispatcher.forward(request, response);`

Because in my `PhaseListener` am checking the `viewId`. And going by above method, the view id always remains to be `index.xtml`. So, am not able to check my conditions.

Comment: Can you please explain some more what you are trying to do in you Servlet?

Comment: I am hitting a Servlet which is a JSF based web application. When Servlet is hit, doPost method is called. index.xhtml is the page I want to render first. So, am achieving it by RequestDispatcher as above. After this PhaseListener gets called. Am also calling this Servlet from another application wherein I dont want to display index.xtml but some other page. But, as per above code it will always redirect to index.xhtml page. So, I dont want to use RequestDispatcher but instead want to call PhaseListener where I can  redirect to appropriate page accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a forward which does not start a new request, so you will keep the original request URI. You need to do a redirect which does start a new request and will give you the new request URI. So need to use:

```
response.sendRedirect("/jsp/html/index.jsf");
```

Note that `response.sendRedirect()` will set the [status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to 302. If you need a 301 status, you need to use:

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader("Location", "/jsp/html/index.jsf");
```